# Array of HTML buttons with on click event to return an attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an array of buttons with an onclick event alerting an attribute.
the buttons are created with no problem and every time I create a problem I set up an alert of the attribute. this works perfect.

Every time you press a button, the right function is called, and it works great, but for some reason I get the second alert to say "undefined"

Just look at the code, it explains it self better then I can.

```
var i = 0
var insertframe = function () {                
            savebutton[i].index = i
            //this works!
            alert(savebutton[i].index)
            savebutton[i].click(function (event) {
                //this returns "undefined" 
                alert(savebutton[i].index)
            })
            i++
        }
```

Solution:

instead of naming the object, I had to use "this" instead so, instead of:

```
savebutton[i].index
```

use:

```
this.index
```

Comment: I think it is just `this.index` or `event.target.index` .

Comment: solved it.

I had to use "this"
 

       var i=0
       var insertframe = function () {
            savebutton[i].index = i
            alert(savebutton[i].index)
            savebutton[i].click(function (event) {
                alert(this.index)
            })
            i++
        }